# R language package ltm issue with library command

Tags: r

I am hoping the someone can answer a short question on ltm.

ltm installs successfully with

```
 install.packages("ltm")
```

but the library command:

```
 library(ltm)
```

throws this error:

> library(ltm)
>   Error: package ‘polycor’ required by ‘ltm’ could not be found

I cannot locate polycor in the install.packages menu in RStudio.

This documentation on ltm: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ltm/ltm.pdf does not mention polycor

I have used this package before without a problem, but it has been about one year since I last used it.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe it's an R version issue...I found this: Title Polychoric and Polyserial Correlations,Depends R (>= 3.3.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update R. From [CRAN polycor info](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/polycor.pdf) it says the package depends on R>3.3.0.  Additionally, [this site](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polycor/index.html) may help.

If you are using linux, you should be able to type: `R --version` into a terminal to confirm which version you have

edit: though it appears my R version is 3.2.3...I may need to change my ubuntu repo

```
 sudo apt-cache showpkg r-base
 sudo apt-get upgrade r-base
 sudo apt-get install r-base
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous contributor is right, you need to update your R version first and not through Rstudio. And then after you've done that proceed and install manually the polycor package via rstudio.

A) Update R

1) go to http://www.r-project.org,
2) click on 'CRAN',
3)then choose the CRAN site that you like. I used St Andrews, Scotland: http://star-www.st-andrews.ac.uk/cran/
click on 'Download R for XXX' [where XXX is your operating system]
follow the installation procedure for your operating system
resart RStudio

B) Install the polycor package using R studio:

I was interested in installing the ltm package but also needed polycor.

This is the code that did the trick for me - type it to the console:

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/polycor_0.7-9.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Thanks